# Rename a drive label in Java

Tags: java, file, java-io, r.java-file

I have an external drive labelled as Anthony's Drive on my windows system,

How can i change the name (rename) of the  drive using java, just as you would simply rename it using file explorer.

I can get the drive label using FileSystemView class in java,
now i can i rename this drive label.

```
public class File_Iterate_3_1 {

private static final String drive_path = "F:\\";
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("File system roots returned by FileSystemView.getFileSystemView():");
    FileSystemView fsv = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView();
    File file = new File(drive_path);
    if(file.exists()){
        System.out.println("File Exists");
        System.out.println("File Label " + fsv.getSystemDisplayName(file));
    }
}
}
```

Above is the code to get the drive label
How do i rename this drive label

Answer (score 0):

First you need admin rights on windows 7 or greater. Second this sounds like a bad idea within Java. And it sounds like if you really would, you have to make native calls. But this is only OS specific. What if you are on Linux, OSX? No Drive Letter anymore.

Little think about: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/03/14/change-drive-letters-and-labels-via-a-simple-powershell-command.aspx

Answer (score 0):

on windows you can use

```
  Runtime.getRuntime().exec("label H:xyz");
```

where H is the drive letter and xyz is the name.